How to pin Firefox icon to Dash?
This is on Ubuntu 24.04 and Firefox is snap. I managed to launch it up and now I would like to pin FireFox icon to Dash. Usually in prior versions, an icon of the application will show in Dash with a menu item of "Pin to Dash" when the application is running. But now, I cannot see any such icon in Dash for Firefox, so I don't know how to pin FireFox to Dash. Can you teach me how?

Please append to your question the result of 'echo $XDG_DATA_DIRS'.  It should contain the path '/var/lib/snapd/desktop' If not you may be able to copy the icon from '/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/{Name}.desktop' to ~/.local/share/applications/'

@david: echo $XDG_DATA_DIRS returns /usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop. Then I followed your instruction to copy /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/firefox_firefox.desktop to ~/.local/share/applications/, and the icon of FireFox appears and gets pinned immediately in Dash. It's magical! Thank you so much, david! Would you please write an answer? I will accept it.

An addition: the command in Exec field of the desktop file does not work in my environment, so I change it to Exec=sh -c "xhost +;env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/bus firefox", which is how I managed to run snap version of FireFox.

Environment variable $XDG_DATA_DIRS should point to /var/lib/snapd/desktop which should find it.
If it does point to it and the icon is not showing (and it exists in /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications) then there is probably something else wrong - possibly a permission not set right. You can fix it temporarily by just copying the file as follows: -
cp /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/firefox_firefox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/

I hope this is of some help.
